# Python Classification Model

Tags: python, classification

I have a df with many columns of info about Home Depot customer accounts. Some fields are accountname, industry, territory, country, state, city, services, etc...
I need to build a model using python that will allow me to put in a customer accountname and I will get an output of customer accounts similar to the one I put in.

So let’s say I put in customeraccount ‘Jon Doe’
I want to get other customer accounts similar to Jon Doe based on features like industry, country, other categorical variables etc..

How can I approach this? What kind of a model would I need to build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create some metric for "closeness" - your definition of distance.

You need a way to compare all (or all relevant to you) fields of a record with the others.

The best/easiest skeletal function I can come up with right now is

```
def rowDist(rowA, rowB):
  return industryDistance(rowA.industry, rowB.industry) \
    * industryDistanceWeight + geographicalDistance(rowA, rowB) \
    * geographicalDistanceWeight
```

Then you just search for rows with lowest distance.